# How to get adapter setting (IPs, MASK, DNS,...) from corrupted Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ip

I want to get adapter setting from my corrupted Windows 7. Windows are now unbootable and unrepairable. I have got a ubuntu live dvd so I have access to all files. Is somewhere in Widows some file with those settings? thank a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the Windows Registry using the chntpw tool in Ubuntu, instructions are here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1527985

And once you're in the Registry, the TCP/IP settings are stored here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314053

Grab a coffee and get settled :)